# Reload a Windows Form from another Form with VB .NET 4+

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Using Visual Studio 2010, WinForms, and VB.Net, I am trying to use one form as a "User Settings" page (Form2) that contains a "Theme" variable for Form1. Basically after a user enters a different theme name (which will eventually be a dropdown list) into the user settings and clicks the save button, I want Form1 to be redrawn or reloaded with the new theme settings.

I have tried to use refresh, hide/show Form1, recall the form_load event, and many other things. I have looked online for a method to redraw or unload/reload the form1 with the new theme setting, but I haven't found anything that works and will change the color settings of form1 once the user saves the user settings on form2.

According to the logic and the documents I have read, one of these options should work, but none of them change the background color of the form1. I have tried calling the ColorChange on load event, on shown event, etc.

I don't want to use the Color Dialog because I don't want the user to select individual colors. I want them to choose from a selection of pre-designed themes that are saved in the user settings. This is only a test project so you can let me know the good and bad about doing it this way while suggesting other ways to do it, but I would much rather understand the reason that none of these options work and figure out a way to make it work if it is possible.

#### Form1

```
Dim selectedTheme As String = My.Settings.Theme

Sub ColorChange()
    Select Case selectedTheme
        Case "Desert"
            Me.BackColor = Color.Brown
        Case "Default"
            Me.BackColor = Color.Black
            lblErrorMsgs.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End Select

End Sub
```

#### Form2

```
Private Sub btnSaveSettings_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveSettings.Click
    My.Settings.Theme = txtTheme.Text
    My.Settings.Save()

    Form1.Refresh()
    Form1.Show()

    Me.Hide()

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you calling the ColorChange Sub after changing the theme?  Did not see the call in the code you posted, perhaps it is somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to call it with a Form Shown event, I've also tried calling it on a button click event. it just doesn't seem to redraw the form or color the background at all. But if I close the application and re-run it the background color will be different.

Comment: Apperently it has to do with the application settings being "cached" If I replace the Refresh/Hide/Show on form2 with         Application.Restart()

The application will shut down, clear the cache and reload the app, where the background color shows up correctly.

Comment: Would you put .. **msgbox(selectedTheme)** before **Select Case selectedTheme** .. what you get ?

Comment: I've added it, no matter what I try to do nothing will trigger the event when I hide form1 then show it again from form2. I've tried using the Shown event, the Activated event . . . if I put another button on form1 to load the theme, I can get it to work . . . but I don't want the user to have to do another event to trigger loading the theme. If I do it on selectionChanged on form2, it doesn't change it when Form1 is shown again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that with calling `Refresh` or `Show` none of the code you have shown here in your Form1 is going to be executed. So your variable `selectedTheme` still holds the previous value and your colorchange is not invoked.

Fortunately the `My.Settings` instance derives from [ApplicationBaseSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase_events(v=vs.110).aspx) which provides the [`PropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

By adding an event handler to your form load event you can use that feature:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler My.Settings.PropertyChanged, AddressOf HandlePropChanged
End Sub
```

Now we need a method that will process the that event:

```
'Imports System.ComponentModel
Private Sub HandlePropChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs)
    If e.PropertyName = "Theme" Then
        selectedTheme = My.Settings.Theme
        ColorChange()
    End If
End Sub
```

As you can see the [PropertyChangedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) has a `PropertyName` that tells you which property actually changed.

You can now change the My.Setting properties anywhere in your app without having to call Refresh or Show after doing so.

Your code in Form2 gets reduced to:

```
Private Sub btnSaveSettings_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveSettings.Click
    My.Settings.Theme = txtTheme.Text
    My.Settings.Save()

    Me.Hide()

End Sub
```